# Possible Improvement of Code

Tags: tabularray

**Code**

Consider the following example:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 1.8cm]{geometry} % to avoid `overfull \hbox'
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  hline{1}   = {2-7}{solid},
  hline{2-Z} = {solid},
  vline{1}   = {2-7}{solid},
  vline{2-Z} = {solid}
}
  & \SetCell{c, m, 1.75cm}
    Utilstræk\-keligt
  & \SetCell{c, m, 1.75cm}
    Tilstræk\-keligt
  & \SetCell{c, m, 1.75cm}
    Jævnt
  & \SetCell{c, m, 1.75cm}
    Godt
  & \SetCell{c, m, 1.75cm}
    Frem\-ragende \\
    \SetCell[r = 1]{h, m, 5.9cm}
    Samarbejdet har fungeret og eventuelle problemer er blevet løst
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &  \\
    \SetCell[r = 1]{h, m, 5.9cm}
    Tiden er blevet disponeret fornuftigt
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &  \\
\end{tblr}%

\end{document}
```

The [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package is fairly new to me.

**Question**

Can the code somehow be improved? (I know that this is a subjective question.)

Comment: Unrelated to your code, but your table would look more professional without all the vertical lines.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I totally agree; the problem is that some of my students have a really head time focusing, so marked cells for everything helps them to some extend. Thanks for you suggestion, none the less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Instead of specifying the alignment for each cell individually, you could do this globally in the table settings
- Instead of hard coding the width of the cells, I would let `tabularray` do this for you. If you use `X` columns, tabularray will automatically distribute them evenly and with something like `X[4]` you can make the first column wider than the other columns.

---

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 1.8cm]{geometry} % to avoid `overfull \hbox'
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  cells={m,c},
  colspec={X[4,l,h]XXXXX},
  hline{1}   = {2-7}{solid},
  hline{2-Z} = {solid},
  vline{1}   = {2-7}{solid},
  vline{2-Z} = {solid}
}
  & Utilstræk\-keligt
  & Tilstræk\-keligt
  & Jævnt
  & Godt
  & Frem\-ragende \\
  Samarbejdet har fungeret og eventuelle problemer er blevet løst
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &  \\
  Tiden er blevet disponeret fornuftigt
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &  \\
\end{tblr}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I can see from your screenshot that the last column is slightly wider than the other four -- can I somehow make all five exactly the same width? (I'm not near a computer at the moment so I can't try myself.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Fixed! I forgot one `X` in the columns declaration, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

For information, here is a way to create that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1.8cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{V[l]{7cm}*{5}{X[c]}}[hvlines,corners=NW,cell-space-limits=3pt]
  & Utilstræk\-keligt
  & Tilstræk\-keligt
  & Jævnt
  & Godt
  & Frem\-ragende \\
  Samarbejdet har fungeret og eventuelle problemer er blevet løst \\
  Tiden er blevet disponeret fornuftigt \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]